# How to Sharpen Images for iPhone Usage

Tags: ios, iphone, image, pixel-manipulation

I have some images that i want to use on my iphone application. The problem is i think that the resolution is not right cause its not sharp at all when see it on the device. This is how it looks when i zoom in a bit on it:

[image]

The idea is to use this image as an image for a UITabBarItem.

Any help and general advice on how to make it sharper & better etc.. or how to make images for iPhone devices and make @2x, @3x etc??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab bar icon size will be displayed about 25 x 25 point. (maximum: 48 x 32)

What does it mean?

Assume, you would like to use an `watch.png`as the tabBar icon.
So you need three icon to achieve it:

- watch.png -> 25 x 25 pixel (for iPhone without retina display)
- watch@2x.png -> 50 x 50 pixel ((maximum: 96 x 64 - for iPhone 6, 5, 5s)
- watch@3x.png -> 75 x 75 pixel (maximum: 144 x 96 - for iPhone 6 Plus)

For more details see  [[Human Interface Design]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Of course, you need a vector graphic image to achieve it and export it in the 3 size. A designer should know the details.
Or you can buy some icons (/download some free icons) in your topic. Several flat icon set are available, e.g.:

- [www.flaticon.com](http://www.flaticon.com/packs/ios7-set-lined-1)
- http://www.pixeden.com/free-icons-set

Comment: There is no chance for a beginner to be able to make the image sharper for iPhone usage and to support all versions mentioned above?

Comment: If the original icon has not enough resolution for @3x, than it is not possible to upscale it and even keep it's original sharps. So you have to download/buy a similar icon for iOS (I added some possible resource into my answer).